# Write to a Microsoft Access database file with Python3

Tags: python, database, python-3.x

For a school project I am to write and organize a set of data to a Microsoft Access database file. I am fairly comfortable with using python to read and write to files but can't find any information online regarding what I am specifically looking for.

I want to know what i would need to do to write to a database in specific Columns and Tables, for example, write the variable "name" in a field called "name" instead of just randomly adding it to the database.

EDIT: I cannot use any additional packages when doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PyODBC](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc). Here is [an example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Database_Programming#pyodbc).

Edit: "no extra modules" is nice but unless you want to re-write pyodbc from scratch you may as well just use it.

Edit2: if you want to know what that would look like, check out [pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc/) - a pure-python odbc driver in about 3000 lines of Python code.

Comment: I am not allowed to actually implement separate modules into the program, is there no way to do it without or would simply writing like you would to a normal file (file.write(...)) work?

Comment: @Zunea: I would suggest getting the pypyodbc source code and copying over just the minimum bits your code needs to work (keep borrowed code in a separate section and attribute it properly, though!).